# Removing certain characters from string in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the string bp which is set at

```
s1 = '[\'<li class="list__item">Accommodates most miter saws; free adapter brackets ' \
'for offset mounting holes with holes included</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">' \
'Trigger handle quick release tool mounts for mounting or removing miter saw ' \
'quickly and easily</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Adjustable arms extend out to ' \
'provide 116 in. of material support</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Fast and easy ' \
'setup with snap pin lock folding legs</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Easy height ' \
'adjustment of material supports with no tools required</li>\', \'<li ' \
'class="list__item">Stand collapses down quickly for easy storage and transport</li>\', ' \
'\'<li class="list__item">20 in. quick attach tool mounts may be used as miter saw base ' \
'on most surfaces</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Durable powder-coated finish</li>\', ' \
'\'<li class="list__item">Includes: folding portable miter saw stand and operator ' \
' manual</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">90-day returnable</li>\']'
```

I want to remove all the '[\' and \ and the commas
Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Where did you *get* this data? Looks like HTML, and you shouldn't be handling HTML with regex

Comment: You do not really have these characters in your string. They simply mean that whatever follows (a `'`) is not really a string delimiter. Try `print`ing your string - you wont' see them.

Comment: character escapers are escaped automatically when you use a string.

Comment: I have just realized by error there, I got the answer funny enough after I realized that was my mistake. Thanks guys!

Comment: @cricket_007 why we can't handle this with regex...using re.sub wht's the harm?

Comment: @prabhat (X)HTML is not a *regular language* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @fork Feel free to answer your post below to show your mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what to replace them with so I'll replace them with empty strings

```
#!python3

s1 = '[\'<li class="list__item">Accommodates most miter saws; free adapter brackets ' \
'for offset mounting holes with holes included</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">' \
'Trigger handle quick release tool mounts for mounting or removing miter saw ' \
'quickly and easily</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Adjustable arms extend out to ' \
'provide 116 in. of material support</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Fast and easy ' \
'setup with snap pin lock folding legs</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Easy height ' \
'adjustment of material supports with no tools required</li>\', \'<li ' \
'class="list__item">Stand collapses down quickly for easy storage and transport</li>\', ' \
'\'<li class="list__item">20 in. quick attach tool mounts may be used as miter saw base ' \
'on most surfaces</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">Durable powder-coated finish</li>\', ' \
'\'<li class="list__item">Includes: folding portable miter saw stand and operator ' \
' manual</li>\', \'<li class="list__item">90-day returnable</li>\']'

s1 = s1.replace("[", "").replace("\\", "").replace(",", "").replace("]", "")

print(s1)
```